# Hibernate aliasing issue with SQL Server

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my application I have a scenario where I have to query a table to get the count of two fields, in order to do that I had to add aliasing of the two count since hibernate flags error when the field names are not aliased. For aliasing I'm not using 'as' keyword. I could find that the query gets executed successfully when there is no pagination done, but when I do pagination the query breaks stating "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'"

Please find the code snippet that Im using to retrieve the data

```
String queryString = "select field1, field2, count(a) count1, count(b) count2 from new_test";
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
query = setQueryParameters(query, parameters);
query.setFirstResult(start);
query.setMaxResults(chunkSize);
return query.getResultList();
```

Please find below the stacktrace of the exception caused :-

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:445)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getGenericOverrideDeniedResult(Unknown Source)
..
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2116)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1898)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:318)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:567)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:436)
... 92 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:283)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)`
```

Comment: you are taking count then why pagination?

Comment: Not only the count im selecting in the original query.i will edit the question.

Comment: You use native SQL. Just place your pagination in the queryString and don't use setFirstResult/setMaxResults at all

Comment: I issue that i face to place my pagination script in queryString is that my application supports both SQLServer and Oracle. So i will have to write query for both databases where ever i encounters this scenario.

Comment: Clearly the "AS" is optional in SQLServer but ought to work with it, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx  so if you get an exception about AS then why not actually post the exception+stack trace and people can comment on it

Comment: I have updated the question with the stack trace

Comment: put the SQL that was invoked (in the log) to get that stack trace, then there is consistent info